# What is the range on Orisa's Halt if it hits an object?

Tags: overwatch

I know the range on Orisa's Halt is 7.5 meters but is this at all shortened if the Halt attack hits a wall, object, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken right from the [Overwatch Gamepedia](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Orisa): (Minus the irrelevant parts to the question)

- **When the orb collides with a surface or when the ability is pressed again,** after a ~0.6s delay, it quickly sucks in enemies **within 7.5m**, applies a brief slow, then dissipates.
- **The projectile itself goes through barriers, but the pull effect will not affect anyone behind a barrier.**

**No matter what it hits, or when it's reactivated, it always pulls enemies within the 7.5m range as long as they are in sight of it. If they get outside of it during that brief .6 second delay, they won't be pulled which could be where you see some discrepancy**

Note: It can go through shields when launched/moving, but the shields only prohibit the pull upon activation, it doesn't actually impact/change the range of the ability.

Answer (score 6):

The range at which an enemy can be "grabbed" by Orisa's halt is always the same and cannot be affected by any skills. Even if Orisa dies before reactivating the skill, the orb will still pull in enemies once it detonates after hitting an obstacle. However, the grab effect cannot go through walls or shields.

Comment: Why do you say "most skills"? What can the radius be affected by?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Just shields and Mei's Ice Wall.

Comment: That doesn't affect the range of the ability

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Not directly, but since the grab cannot affect people behind shields or walls, the grab range is "reduced" by the shield/wall.

Comment: If you say that, then you have to say that hitting a wall does reduce Halt's range. But that's ridiculous, the range is always the same and not affected by shields or walls.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Are you saying that if you detonate the orb in front of a Reinhardt with his shield up, the Reinhardt will be pulled forward? I can tell you from experience that is not the case. I'm not talking about how far you can shoot the orb - I'm talking about the grab range after the orb is detonated.

Comment: Once again, the range of the effect is always the same. The fact that it doesn't go through walls is completely irrelevant.

Comment: I think what they're getting at is your wording. Yes Rein will not be pulled forward due to his shield. *However*, that does not alter the range of the pull. It prohibits it, but does not alter it.

Comment: I've edited my answer to hopefully be more *technically* clear.

Answer (score -2):

No, the radius of the effect is exactly the same.